# Visual Studio Extension: How to disable native command?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I build an extension that manages correctly Git Modules and, to do so, I have a folder in the solution called SubModules.

I managed to add my context menu to the solution file and to the project files, but I would like to disable some native commands when right-clicking on my SubModules folder (i.e. Remove, Add).

Is there a way to disable such native command?

I tried exploring EnvDTE80.DTE2.Commands, but no luck and searching tells me how to disable my own commands (which I already know how).

My extension is developed in C#, but an answer in VB.Net is alright too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to commandEvents.BeforeExecute, check the command name in the handler and set CancelDefault = true to disable a command. See [Add confirmation before running Build.RebuildSolution and other rebuild commands](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#RebuildConfirmation).

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you a lot. May I complete this question or open a new one? I am now missing how to know the "path" of a solution folder. I found something, but was not able to access it.

Comment: @MasterDJon You need to open a new question as it is a different topic.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54607817/visual-studio-extension-how-to-get-the-path-of-a-solution-folder-on-selection

Comment: Thank you for your first help!

Comment: Did you take a look at my new question?

Comment: I found on your site the answer.